# Как сделать группу виджетов Tkinter на одной перемнной?

Tags: tkinter

У меня есть переменная к которой привязан условный виджет. Как сделать чтобы я мог создать много виджетов одного типа(к примеру Label) но с разными значениями? И так чтобы потом каждым отдельно мог управлять?

К примеру:

```
txtName = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frmNAME, 
                                 text="Загрузка...", 
                                 text_color="black",
txtName.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.25)
```

Надо создать 5 текстов с разной позицией и самим текстом?
И да, такое вообще возможно, ведь у меня будет браться множество разных вариаций, и так чтобы предыдущий виджет не удалялся и даже мог редактироваться.

Дааа, понимаю, звучит жестко и не реально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суешь все `Lables` в массив (там сохраняются истинные названия `Label`) и позже через `.config` к каждому обращаешься

Вот пример:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

def foo(a):
    LABELS[a].config(bg = 'red')

names = ['alice', 'mark', 'peter']
LABELS=[]
for i in range(len(names)):
    lb = Label(root, text = names[i])
    lb.pack()
    LABELS.append(lb)

foo(2)

root.mainloop()
```